# Do UEFI BIOS and OS have to be of the same 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: operating-system, bios, uefi

Can 32bit UEFI BIOS work with 64bit OS or vice versa? I don't think it can, or at least it shouldn't. But it seems to be possible according to [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/853009/possible-to-install-64-bit-windows-on-32-bit-uefi).

For a CPU capable of both 32bit and 64bit, it's just a matter of operating mode I think. And I believe it's switchable. So is there any technical reason that makes it impossible or inappropriate for mixed OS/BIOS arch?

Comment: Stackoverflow is reserved for programming questions. This question may be a better fit on super user.

Comment: I don't agree with this close reason, and I would like to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, the short answer is: it depends on your architecture.

On x86 it *is* possible, if a little bit fiddly. A whole class of 64-bit devices shipping with 32-bit UEFI are supported out of the box by at least Debian's amd64 port ([more info](https://blog.einval.com/2015/03/30#Jessie-EFI_6)).

On ARM it is not, or rather 32-bit OS on 64-bit UEFI is technically possible (only would still require the operating system loader to be 64-bit), but even fiddlier than on x86. Launching a 64-bit operating system from 32-bit firmware is simply not supported by the architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From your answer I got a picture of how FW and OS can work together as of now. Is there any technical reason behind this fact?

Comment: Runtime services bitness [basically](http://vzimmer.blogspot.com/2013/02/32-versus-64-bit-and-measuring-uefi.html). It's not impossible then to separate the two things, but it requires quite some extra abstraction.